# Sieve of Eratosthenes C++

Tags: c++, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, sieve

currently I'm working on a project, where I want to calculate all prime numbers.
When I compile (MINGW Windows Comp.) the programm crashes and returns a random error number.
This is the Code I've written:

http://pastebin.com/4vVnAM2v

```
/*
    Sieb des Eratosthenes
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    //variablendeklaration
    unsigned int nmax=100;
    unsigned int i,j,erg;
    bool prim[nmax];

    //Initialisieren
    prim[0]=false;
    prim[1]=false;

    //array prim[i] erstellen
    for(i=2;i<nmax;i++)
    {
        prim[i]=true;
    }




    for(i=2;i<nmax;i++) //alle Primzahlen durchlaufen
    {
        if(prim[i] == true) //auf Prim prüfen
        {
            for(j=2;j<nmax;j++) //multiplizieren und wegstreichen
            {
                erg = j * i;
                prim[erg] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=2;i<nmax;i++)
    {
        cout << prim[i] << endl;
    }


}
```

Comment: Unless you're prohibited - use vector instead - `vector<bool> primes;`

Comment: When you start using fairly large numbers (e.g. > 1 million), this O(n^2) version of the sieve will take forever.

Answer (score 1):

At this point:

```
            erg = j * i;
            prim[erg] = false;
```

you are going to eventually access beyond the bounds of `prim`, since both `i` and `j` can have a value of up to `nmax - 1`, so `erg` will have a max value of `(nmax - 1) * (nmax - 1)`. You need to check for this condition and break if `erg >= nmax`, e.g.

```
            erg = j * i;
            if (erg < nmax)          // if i * j still within bounds
                prim[erg] = false;   // set prim[i * j] to false
            else                     // else i * j now >= nmax
                break;               // break out of loop and try next i value
```

Comment: what does it mean?
do I have to change the var "nmax" in the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this problem is to avoid extra steps in your loop:

```
for(i=2; i < nmax; i++)
{
    if(prim[i] == true)
    {
        for (j = 2 * i; j < nmax; j += i) // state j at 2i, increment by i
        {
            prim[j] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This has the effect of 1) not looping through `nmax` items nested (reducing your overall complexity from O(n^2) to O(n * (n/2 + n/6 + n/10 + ...) which is effectively O(n log n), and 2) not requiring an additional bounds check since you are never going out of bounds in your looping condition.